# How do I get up on High Hrothgar to the Greybeards?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm following the main quest and I need to get up to the Greybeard's monastery High Hrothgar. The quest marker first lead me to Ivarstead, and then I tried to find a way up the mountain.

I haven't found a way up yet and I am nearly around half of the mountain now. The Clairvoyance spell also doesn't help, it just says "unable to find a direct path". How do I get up this mountain?

Comment: My problem exactly. I tried walking and even horse-riding all the way up, but I can't seem to find a way past the last mile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There should be stairs near a bridge in Ivarstead (you know you're near it when you can get a quest from an npc to deliver food to the Greybeards), just go up those, however sometimes they end for a bit, however the path is generally linear to High Hrothgar. Just look around for some more steps.

The [UESP page for the quest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Way_of_the_Voice) is a bit vague, but might be of some help.

Comment: The path never actually stops it is just covered by snow, also i think you get something for reading all the placks in those stone thingies.

Comment: This doesn't warrant its own question so I'm going to ask here: Did you guys also come across a sabertooth cat on your way up there? It seemed really suspiciously placed in the middle of the stairs, halfway up. It was a content blocker since I had to level up to around level 12 or so to defeat it before I could move up (since it's way faster than you even when sprinting)

Comment: @heishe I came across several enemies on this path, including a spider and a frost troll. Can't remember one way or the other about a sabertooth cat though.

Answer (score 0):

At one point there is a hidden trail that is covered in snow. Sometimes you have to first go down to then go back up again.